# Can I abstract Microsoft.Maui.Storage.Preferences as IPreferences in MAUI

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, maui

I'm writing a .NET MAUI app and I would like to use [Microsoft.Maui.Storage.Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-6.0&tabs=android) in my ViewModel, however would prefer not to tie my ViewModel to the static `Preferences` class otherwise it will be hard to test. So I noticed there is an `IPreferences` interface, but I don't know what it's purpose is, as I can't inject a static implementation (and Preferences is static).

In my startup class I do the usual `builder.Services.AddSingleton()` and `.AddTransient()`:

```
builder.Services
        .AddSingleton<AppShell>()
        .AddTransient<MyViewModel>()
        ...
```

But I can't do this with a static class. This won't work because you can't use a static class as a type argument:

```
        .AddSingleton<IPreferences, Preferences>()
```

This doesn't work because it's not provided by the framework:

```
        .AddSingleton<IPreferences>()
```

And I tried to get fancy:

```
        .AddSingleton<IPreferences>(_ => Preferences.Default)
```

but I get this error when using it:

```
    _preferences.Get("SomeKey", DateTime.Now); // error here, but _preferences is defined
```

```
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Storage.PreferencesImplementation.Get[DateTime](String key, DateTime defaultValue, String sharedName) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Essentials\src\Preferences\Preferences.android.cs:line 141
[mono-rt]    at ... my filenames removed ... in ...\Shells\AppShell.xaml.cs:line 51
[mono-rt]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
[mono-rt]    at Android.App.SyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:line 36
[mono-rt]    at Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:line 36
[mono-rt]    at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:line 84
[mono-rt]    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 22
```

Can I inject IPreferences or do I have to create my own interface backed by the static Preferences?

Comment: It should be able to work as per your "fancy" solution. On what platform are you seeing this? Does it work on other platforms? Does it work on other types than `DateTime`?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Android emulator, Android 7.0 API 24.

Comment: Additional, are you on .NET 6 or 7? I see there was a bug with this and it's fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/9974

Might be part of .NET 7 that was just released.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis .NET 6 because LTS... It is failing on a DateTime so you may have answered it! Do you know how to tell if this is/will be backported to .NET 6?

Comment: I don't think this is likely to be ported to .NET 6. I do see this is available in .NET 7. Also the regular LTS rules don't apply to .NET MAUI (see here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/maui) so you might want to consider going to .NET 7 anyway.

Comment: I can confirm. In my 6.0 project, calling this causes exception. In my 7.0 it works without problem.

Answer (score 7):

IPreferences is for saving small key-value pairs.
You can inject it referencing Preferences.Default.

And then use:

```
settings.Get("Language", 0);
```

Where settings is:

```
IPreferences settings;
```

What I like to do is make SettingsService, and then use:

```
public int Language
{
    get => settings.Get("Language", 0);
    set => settings.Set("Language", value);
}
```

There are other ways to handle your settings, but for few values, this works for me.

Edit(The code you requested.)

Injecting:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISettings>(new SettingsService(Preferences.Default));
```

ISettings interface:

```
public interface ISettings
{
    int Language { get; set; }
}
```

SettingsService class:

```
internal class SettingsService : ISettings
{
    IPreferences settings;

    public SettingsService(IPreferences settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public int Language
    {
        get => settings.Get("Language", 0);
        set => settings.Set("Language", value);
    }
}
```

Using in ViewModel:

```
public MyViewModel(ISettings settings)
{
    lang = settings.Language;
}
```

Edit2: since you do not want to "manually construct". You can do this.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPreferences>(Preferences.Default);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISettings, SettingsService>();
```

With this you can use IPreferences, as well as ISettings. And SettingsService constructor will use the IPreferences injected here.

Comment: How do I inject it though? Can you show the builder.Servcies.Add... code?

Comment: I've added the code you want.

Comment: OK, so not really a way to inject Preferences.Default as an implementation of IPreferences, I have to (as I alluded to in my question) create my own interface backed by the static Preferences. I prefer not to use manaul construction as the services are not created by the container and hence not disposed, which is probably why you used a singleton. It may be my only option though... thanks.

Comment: You can use IPreferences too. I just don't want to write prefrences.Get("some string", defaultValue) every time. First - because I don't want to deal with those keys, second - because I don't want to deal with those default values, and most importantly third - tomorrow when I have to change something, I don't want to go through all my code and replace those everywhere. You don't HAVE TO back this up, but it is highly recommended.

Comment: I have edited it again, so there is no "manual construction".

Comment: And that's when I get the exception. It's a good answer, I've upvoted you because it will be helpful to someone I'm sure, but it's not my specific problem.

Comment: The source I give you is from working project. Show me where and how you use this.

Comment: It is not the injection, it is not the preferences, it is the DataTime you are using. change it to preferences.Get("somekey", 0) and you will see it will work. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8853

Comment: Wow the Maui group has created a train wreck here.