# .NET Maui how to make use of IOptionsSnapshot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, maui

Basically I'm trying to work around the fact that you can't really use `IOptionsSnapshot` in Maui since the `appsettings.json` file is set in stone once it's bundled in with the app.

Manually updating the `IConfiguration` with `Configuration["key"] = myValue`
require then to notify all scoped services or singletons to retrieve new istances of their `IOptionsSnapshot` properties.
Yep I need to update those options at runtime. (Even autofac moved from this)

So I either use ApiControllers which are transient that are locally to the app and I don't know if Maui supports them, so the requests always have the updated options.
Or I make use of transient services and resolve them manually every time I need them with

```
using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyTransientService>()
```

Comment: You can refer to the official documentation: [Use IOptionsSnapshot to read updated data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#use-ioptionssnapshot-to-read-updated-data)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you need to do few things.

First, make a settings service, that stores and reads small key-value pairs:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74402836/6643940

Now you have to make sure, that everyone is notified about changes.

In my case it is easy:

Using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, I implement Messaging.

Setting a property sends a message, for whoever cares about those changes. If there is something running, and has subscribed for that message, it will receive it.

Otherwise I fire something, that no one listens to (and this is not bad thing).

The good thing for me is that, I don't even have this Service in the places that I want to detect a change. Everything is de-coupled.

The stuff that DOES use this service, it gets the new values anyway, and since this is singleton, you can add other properties that will be updated for everyone.

The interesting part here, is that custom code you have to write. At one place you may have BaseAddress setting of HttpClient. Good luck remembering that you have to re-construct it when changed.

People are not doing this during runtime for a reason. You will infest your code with bugs.

Comment: The nice thing about IOptionsSnapshot is that you wont need to worry about polluting the code, IF ONLY there was an easy way to make it work. In AspNetCore you can change the appsettings and reload all the options. 
Also you manually set options and make different services from different scopes, so every scope will have services with only the correct options. Meh.

Comment: @Taunterexd I also want access to all the instruments of AspNetCore. The reality however is that we have to live with what MAUI has to offer. Injecting a settings service as singleton is not that bad, as most people say. And basing it on the default Preferences makes your code run on every platform. Do not give up however, maybe you can find something windows specific. I am just the wrong guy for that.

Comment: No worries, thank you for the help. It's something i already did but i was searching for an alternative. 
The way i do it now is that I manually create scopes and for every scope i resolve one service that has the correct scoped options but that's a mess too. If no one else answer i will accept your.